# total $\omega$-limit sets of continuos maps on (compact) metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I have looked up literature on omega limit sets and from what I have seen they consider limit sets of a single point (of a single trajectory, discrete or continuous).

Are there studies that characterize structure and properties of total $\omega$-limit sets, meaning the union of $\omega$-limit sets of all trajectories?

Comment: You might take a look at [this item on chain recurrence](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Chain_recurrence) and the references therein, particularly the work of Charles Conley.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The union of all the $\omega$-limit sets of a function $f:X \rightarrow X$ $\,(X$ is a metric space) is sometimes denoted by $\Lambda(f),\,$ that is, $\,\Lambda(f) = \bigcup_{x \in X}\,\omega(x,f).$ See, for example, [*The persistence of* $\omega$-*limit sets defined on compact spaces*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X13011050) by Emma DʼAniello and Timothy H. Steele (2014). I recommend sending an email to [Steele](https://www.weber.edu/mathematics/Faculty.html) (feel free to say I told you this, as I know him), asking him for some pointers to the kind of results you are interested in pursuing.